# Separating wall construction

Tags: walls

I am working on replacing the wall separating my garage and basement [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELLeZ.jpg).

The floor is cement, and the exterior walls are CMU.

A steel track seems suitable to protect the bottom board of the wall frame.

I am a bit hung up on what to do where the wall meets the CMU blocks. I've read suggestions to glue a strip of foam board directly to the CMU, then plywood, and then anchor the wall through that. I've also read not to connect it to the CMU wall at all, but to leave a 1" space between the separating wall and CMU block.

**What do the experts here say? Should the separating wall connect to the CMU blocks at all? If so, how? If not, what do I do with that gap between the wall and CMU blocks?**

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELLeZ.jpg) The former wall is clearly a DIY deal. They nailed, or rather, tried to nail, what appears to be untreated lumber directly to the cement floor, and one one side even nailed it to the CMU wall. Here are some choice photos:

[image: If you look closely, you can see how someone tried really, really hard to nail the boards into the CMU and cement floor, but did not succeed very well]
[image: Drain pipe doesn't quite fit into your new separating wall? Just cut that pesky drywall out of the way! The fiberglass in this area was one gigantic mouse nest.]

As a bonus: the drain pipe picture LEAKS a little both, so it is definitely responsible for some of that water. Instead of replacing the pipe like a sane person, they slathered some .. plastic glue gunk on it and hoped for the best.

You can't see it now because I scraped it away, but when they realized water was coming out from this wall they.. you guessed it - APPLIED CAULK BETWEEN THE WALL AND THE FLOOR, apparently to keep the bloody water in the bloody wall. </end rant>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Sill Sealer" is what's typically used between a concrete slab and the bottom plate of a wall. I see no reason you couldn't/shouldn't use it between your bottom plate *and* the stud against the wall. I'm reasonably confident that it will last *much* longer than some sort of metal protection. It will also be much easier to install. If you can't get it to stay where you want it, just hold it down with some masking tape during installation, then cut away the extra tape once the wall is standing and secured.

Example of sill sealer:
[image]
<sup>Image courtesy of [lowes.com](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Pregis-Sill-Sealer-3-5-in-x-50-Ft/1002905124). No affiliation with mfgr or retailer, but I used a product like this myself on a now 30 year old garage wall.</sup>

I also see no reason why you *shouldn't* attach the wood wall to the CMU wall. However, you'll need to use the proper fasteners to do so. As you've noted, attempting to drive a framing nail into concrete doesn't work so swell. There are a [squidzillion questions here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/search?q=attach+wood+to+concrete) about attaching things to CMUs, so I won't address that.

Comment: OTOH, I don't know that I'd spend too much time attaching the end stud to the CMU.  I don't think the wall is structural, so as long as the studs are securely fastened to the toe and top plates, it should be fine without being fastened laterally.  I think the biggest issue will be sealing any joints to keep "garage" smells out of the basement.

Comment: _I_ would throw a couple of fasteners in there, @Huesmann, but then my wife accuses me of overdoing everything. I remind her that nothing I build falls down. :D Also, it might be a good excuse to buy a powder-actuated hammer! Whether it _really_ needs to be fastened to the wall may be dependent on how it's fastened at the ceiling, just to keep it from being wobbly and the next home owner making snide remarks on the interwebz about the current owner's workmanship, skills and parentage...

Comment: @FreeMan hah! I was considering a powder-actuated hammer, and questioning the parentage of the former owner. :)

Comment: @FreeMan LOL @ your last.

Comment: As I continue to deconstruct this wall, I find that it's damp pretty much everywhere it touches the concrete floor or CMU wall. There is no water or dampness elsewhere (nearby, anyway). My plan is to demo the wall entirely, and then wait for everything to (visibly) dry out. Do you really think the sill sealer and treated lumber really be enough to prevent this from occurring again, or is there some additional step I could take? (maybe something silly like slathering the floor and walls with dry lock?)

Comment: Concrete will wick moisture. Nature of the beast. Your best bet is to do the work _outside_ to keep as much water away from the foundation as possible. They reason you're seeing moisture under the wood and nowhere else is that the wood is preventing it from evaporating. As noted, sill sealer and PT lumber is the _standard_ (in the US) way of building every wood frame building for probably the last 50+ years. Will it eventually rot? Sure, but you probably won't be around to worry about fixing it... Also, that's probably the way all the other walls in your house were constructed.